# Replicacion Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

intento habilitar la replicacion transacional con suscripciones actualizables y me lanza un error, pero eh buscado informacion y me dice que corra el siguiente procediemiento, pero no me funciona:

```
exec sp_link_publication @publisher = 'GEA-SRVDATA\SQLSERVER2008'
, @publisher_db = 'PalmComSync'
, @publication = 'Palm83'
, @security_mode = '1'
, @login = 'sa'
, @password = 'taramaca01$'
, @distributor = 'GEA-PALM\GEAPALMSERVER'
```

cuando intento correr este procedimiento me lanza el siguiente error, 
O

```
LE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "REPLLINK_GEA-SRVDAT838186658_PALMCOMSYN596908474_PALM831306616318_ALASKA_PCO691301400" returned message "No transaction is active.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "REPLLINK_GEA-SRVDAT838186658_PALMCOMSYN596908474_PALM831306616318_ALASKA_PCO691301400" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

ayuda,

Comment: Para lo del mensaje de error "Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 1", revisa el artículo de la KB de Soporte Microsoft en https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/329332/you-receive-error-7391-when-you-run-a-distributed-transaction-against para configurar adecuadamente el MS DTC.
Luego intentas de nuevo lo de replicación, a ver si te funciona.

Comment: @GuillermoTaylor he leido la documentacion de como configurarlo adecuadamente y no me a funcionado.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir algún mensaje de error o imagen para entender bien a lo que te refieres con "no me ha funcionado", por favor?

Comment: lo coloque hay el error que me da el sql server cuando corro el procedimiento

Comment: ¿Sale el mismo error después de haber realizado lo que indiqué que se revisara en el KB de Soporte Microsoft?

Comment: Si, pero estoy  investigando a ver como lo puedo solucionar